# Возведение в большие степени матрицу по модулю

Tags: c++

Стоит задача возвести матрицу в большую степень по модулю. Примерно как возводить матрицу в степень я понимаю, но если степень большая, то это будет очень долго. Подскажите, пожалуйста как можно это реализовать

Comment: Воспользуйтесь [быстрым возведением в степень](https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%91%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C)

Comment: Для обычного числа понятно как, но как для матрицы, особо непонятно

Comment: Чтобы возвести матрицу в степень, нужно её саму на себя переносить нужное количество раз, т.е. там будет суммирование элементов. Как тут воспользоваться этим быстрым возведением в степень, пока не представляю как

Comment: Ну вы же знаете, как множить матрицы? Вот точно так же - просто вместо числа получается матрица.